# Выборка из 3 связанных таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется следующая структура:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parend_id` INT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `properties` (
  `property_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`type` ENUM('select','text','checkbox','radio') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`property_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property_value` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `property_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property_category` (
  `property_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Нужно получить все свойства определенной категории и их значения.
Можно ли это всё сделать за один запрос? В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно, копать в сторону join

```
select *
from categories cat
join property_category pc on pc.category_id = cat.category_id
join properties p on p.property_id = pc.property_id
join property_value pv on pv.property_id = p.property_id
```

Comment: Зависит от условий, не описанных в задаче. Если необходимо отобразить и категории без свойств/значений, то left join

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить такой вариант (с оговорками - см. ниже)

```sql
SELECT c.*, p.name as property, GROUP_CONCAT(pv.value) as propertyValues 
FROM categories c
JOIN property_category pc ON c.category_id=pc.category_id
JOIN properties p ON pc.property_id=p.property_id
LEFT JOIN property_value pv ON p.property_id=pv.property_id
GROUP BY c.category_id, p.property_id
```

Принципиальное отличие в колонке `propertyValues`. Это будут разделенные запятой значения каждого свойства.

Также хочу обратить внимание на `LEFT JOIN property_value`. Именно `LEFT` потому что для `property` типа `text` таблица `property_value` не будет иметь никаких значений, при этом свойство типа `text` в результат попадет.

И еще хочу оговориться, что `GROUP_CONCAT` имеет ограничения по длине. Так что если у Вас есть свойство с большим количеством значений, мой вариант будет не удобен.

Comment: а как посоветуете лучше хранить значения свойств. Допустим для select все значения в одной колонке через разделитель, или каждое новая запись ? И как пуступить из типом text.

Comment: Для `select`, `radio`, `checkbox` у вас есть таблица `property_value`. Я так понял, что именно там Вы планировали хранить возможные варианты. Так? Тогда Вам нужна еще одна таблица, например `category_property_value` с полями `category_id`, `property_id`, `value`. Причем для `select`, `radio`, `checkbox` колонка `value` этой таблицы будет хранить `id` из `property_value`, а для `text` - это будет текст...

Comment: Да совершенно верно, в property_value планировал хранить варианты.

Comment: Ну вот. А где-то еще Вы должны хранить выбранные `property_value` для каждой `category`. И для этого Вам нужна еще одна сводная таблица

Comment: Ну выбранные значения из property_value я планировал хранить в таблице: `product_value{id, product_id, value_id}`. Сводная таблица, это то что Вы выше (category_property_value) написали. Верно ?

Comment: Да, "сводная таблица" это моя `category_property_value`. Ну или Ваша `product_value`. Только Вам надо еще добавить `category_id`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29784/discussion-between-depredator-and-cyadvert).